# querying XML when there are uneven elements

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

The problem with this code is that there isn't always a CEEBCode in each group. The 1st ceebcode it finds is actually in the second group and that is matched up with the other elements in the 1st group.

Is there anyway to keep the groups together when a ceeb code does not exist?

```
select 
UIN,
docXML.value('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool/CEEBCode/text())[1]' 
    ,'varchar(6)'
    ) as ceeb1,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool/IsGrad/text())[1]'
    ,'varchar(5)'
    ) as IsGradAns1,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool/Country/text())[1]' 
    ,'varchar(25)'
    ) as Country1,
docXML.value('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool/CEEBCode/text())[2]' 
    ,'varchar(6)'
    ) as ceeb2,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool/IsGrad/text())[2]'
    ,'varchar(5)'
    ) as IsGradAns2,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool/Country/text())[2]' 
    ,'varchar(25)'
    ) as Country2
from tblDocument
where docxml is not null
```

Sample XML:

```
<SelfReportedTranscript>
  <HighSchools>
    <SelfReportedHighSchool>
      <Name>Ramay Jr High School</Name>
      <City>Fayetteville</City>
      <Country>United States of America</Country>
      <StateProvince>Arkansas</StateProvince>
      <IsGrad>false</IsGrad>
      <HighSchoolType>Domestic</HighSchoolType>
    </SelfReportedHighSchool>
    <SelfReportedHighSchool>
      <Name>Fayetteville Sr High Sch</Name>
      <CEEBCode>040770</CEEBCode>
      <City>Fayetteville</City>
      <Country>US</Country>
      <StateProvince>AR</StateProvince>
      <IsGrad>true</IsGrad>
      <HighSchoolType>Domestic</HighSchoolType>
    </SelfReportedHighSchool>
  </HighSchools>
</SelfReportedTranscript>
```

This is for SQL Server 2005 SP3

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of the XML?

Comment: i tried.  i don't know if you can see everything i added.

Comment: This worked for the [1] case, but the [2] returned nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Added `[1]` and `[2]` to the `SelfReportedHighSchool` tag since that is where you get the "rows" from. Also needed to change the final `[2]` to `[1]`.

```
select 
UIN,
docXML.value('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool[1]/CEEBCode/text())[1]' 
    ,'varchar(6)'
    ) as ceeb1,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool[1]/IsGrad/text())[1]'
    ,'varchar(5)'
    ) as IsGradAns1,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool[1]/Country/text())[1]' 
    ,'varchar(25)'
    ) as Country1,
docXML.value('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool[2]/CEEBCode/text())[1]' 
    ,'varchar(6)'
    ) as ceeb2,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool[2]/IsGrad/text())[1]'
    ,'varchar(5)'
    ) as IsGradAns2,
docxml.value
    ('
    (/SelfReportedTranscript/HighSchools/SelfReportedHighSchool[2]/Country/text())[1]' 
    ,'varchar(25)'
    ) as Country2
from tblDocument
where docxml is not null
```